# How best to recharge 3.6v Lithium Coin Cell batteries safely from small solar panels?

Tags: battery-charging, solar-cell, batteries, solar-energy

I want to charge 'rechargeable' 3.6v Lithium Coin Cell batteries with one or two 3v 100ma solar panels. Do I need to worry about safety and overcharging the batteries? How can I measure if the batteries are fully charged or not?

Do rechargeable 3.6v Lithium Coin Cell batteries have a small voltage drop happen when fully charged? If so how could I measure that and stop the charging??

Comment: Before asking this question, did you take any trouble to read any technical literature on now to charge Li-Ion batteries? Google? Wikipedia? Batteryuniversity?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to worry about over-charging them, and over-discharging them, and their temperature, and putting too much charging current into them, etc.  You need to build safety into your design.  You'll might take a look at something like this [linear tech solar battery charger](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC4121).  Notice how it has some safety features and a charge controller built into it.  It also has MPPT to which should help you get the most power out of your panels.

I know you want to use a 3V panel but then you'll need to boost the voltage to get high enough to charge them (if you're just using a single panel anyway).